# Xamarin saving a video path in sqlite. Having permission issue to save

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am recording for 7 seconds and after that I want to save the video but I have an error. Trying to save the video. error is =

> Java.IO.IOException: invalid preview surface
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()

The code is

```
  private  void SetupRecording(object sender, EventArgs e)   // start recording
    {

        try
        {
            video.StopPlayback();

            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
            recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
            recorder.SetVideoFrameRate(30);
            recorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);
            recorder.SetOutputFile(path);
            recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(video.Holder.Surface);
            recorder.SetMaxDuration(7000);
            // recording for 7 seconds

            recorder.Prepare();


            try
            {

                Video vid = new Video()
                {
                    ProjectID = passedID,
                    VideoPath = path,

                };
                updatavideodb.insertIntoTableVideo(vid);


            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
            {

                recorder.Stop();
                recorder.Release();
                return;
            }
            recorder.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(8000);
            recorder.Stop();
            recorder.Release();
            textCountDown.Text = " Finshed Recording ";

            CloseCamera();
        }
```

The path i am trying to save to

> path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/test" + time.ToString().Replace("/", "-") + ".mp4";

The manifest is -

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="ShowWorksDemo6.ShowWorksDemo6" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:label="ShowWorksDemo6"></application>
</manifest>
```

the code stop running at the line recorder.Prepare();

I like any help in what I am wrong would be great help.

Comment: this error appears to occur before you even start recording, so it likely has nothing to do with permissions or the file path you're saving to

Answer (score 0):

I would have added this a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet. Take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22213743/6608917) answer. It looks the error is related to this line in your code `recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(video.Holder.Surface);`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue I was having, I was using dispose before I called the the video reorder. Which ended the activity before it should display the recorder. Thanks for your help any way